# Pandas calculate average value of column for rows satisfying condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing information about users rating items during a period of time. It has the following semblance :    [image]

In the dataframe I have a number of rows with identical 'user_id' and 'business_id' which i retrieve using the following code :

```
mask = reviews_df.duplicated(subset=['user_id','business_id'], keep=False) 
dup = reviews_df[mask]
```

obtaining something like this :
[image]

I now need to remove all such duplicates from the original dataframe and substitute them with their average. Is there a fast and elegant way to achive this?Thanks!

Comment: `reviews_df.groupby(['user_id', 'business_id']).mean()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang hehe simpler than i tought, thanks!If you want to make it the answer ill close the post.

Comment: It's OK. This will most likely flagged as duplicated anyway :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang shall I delete the post then?

Comment: Yes, if you feel it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Se if you do have a dataframe looks like

```
   review_id  user_id  business_id  stars        date
0          1        0            3    2.0  2019-01-01
1          2        1            3    5.0  2019-11-11
2          3        0            2    4.0  2019-10-22
3          4        3            4    3.0  2019-09-13
4          5        3            4    1.0  2019-02-14
5          6        0            2    5.0  2019-03-17
```

Then the solution should be something like that:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(['user_id', 'business_id'], keep=False)]\
  .groupby(['user_id', 'business_id'])\
  .apply(lambda x: x.stars - x.stars.mean())
```

With the following result:

```
user_id  business_id   
0        2            2   -0.5
                      5    0.5
3        4            3    1.0
                      4   -1.0
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, the comment under the question solved it. Ill probably post the comment as the answer, but thanks for the time!